# able to view jsp page, on submit getting 404, correct servlet mapping is given in web.xml. May I know if there is any other thing missing?

Tags: java

Tomcat version 8
the below is the servlet mapping. I don't see any mapping miss in web.xml
web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.gurugubelli.controller.LoginController</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

```
  <servlet-name>UserRegistration</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.gurugubelli.controller.RegistrationController</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>UserRegistration</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/userRegistration</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

login.jsp

```
<form action="login" method="POST">
    <label>Enter Username : </label> 
    <input type="text" name="username" required="required"> <br> <br> 
    <label>Enter Password : </label> 
    <input type="password" name="password" required="required"> <br> <br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
   </form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVuAP.png)

Comment: [1] Please add [tomcat] and [tomcat-8] tags to your post. [2] As Goutham pointed out in the answer below, your `<url-pattern>` value should match the value being submitted from the form, and your screen shot shows that the submitted value is **Login** rather than **login**. Your screen shot content for _login.jsp_also differs from the text shown above ("Login" vs. "login").

Answer (score 0):

404 - Page Not Found on the Server, which means that the urlpattern may not be declared or used  properly.
Instead of web.xml, try this
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/login"}) in the LoginController.java file.

Or check the CASE of the urlpattern '/login' or '/Login', it has to be one which is used in form action.